# selected values in multiselect box are remembered the 2nd time popup loads even though I have not written code to remember

Tags: java, javascript, html, velocity

I am using an Apache Velocity Macro (*.vm) template file that contains an HTML multi-selectbox.  The values of this select-box are filled in by the a Java function that returns an ArrayList.

The velocity code loops through the values in this ArrayList of Strings and generates  elements that will be selectable when rendered.

The rendered HTML is displayed by a javascript fancybox popup and the user can select any/all of the values returned by the Java function mentioned above.

The whole operation works perfectly the first time the popup appears.  After the user selects a bunch of values from the multi-selectbox and closes the popup I can use jQuery(#selectbox).val() and gain access the values the user selected without any problems.

However, if the user reopens the popup a 2nd time and selects a different set of values and closes the popup, the jQuery(#selectbox).val() returns the values that were selected the first time! This behavior continues unless I refresh the webpage in the browser.

So my question is: does anybody know what is causing this behavior? Is there any way to stop remembering previously selected values?

In case this is relevant, I'm using Safari 5 on OSx 10.6.4, Apache Tomcat 6, Java 6.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that your fancybox popup call is creating a new dom element with the id #selectbox instead of using the one that was already rendered in the page. Inspect the elements rendered in your page to see if this is the case.

Comment: Carlos - Looks like you are correct! But how do I fix it? It appears like every time the popup appears it's adding new dom element with #selectbox. How do I prevent the popup from embedding itself into the page so as to not confuse jquery?